# Accessing Background of a Webpage with CSS

Tags: html, css, squarespace

I am looking to customize the css of a webpage in Squarespace. I just want to be able to use a linear-gradient background. When inspecting the page, I can get the desired result by editing the `page-section` class with the following code:

```
background: linear-gradient(90deg, black, blue);
```

However, I cannot replicate this change when I look to inject the code into the website permanently. My understanding is that I would do a variant of the following:

```
<style>
#yui_3_17_2_1_1572554735264_404 .page-section {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, black, blue);
}
</style>
```

With my extremely limited knowledge I am looking to use the id and class to limit what I am changing. However this does not seem to properly be accessing the same area that I am changing when I inspect.

Below is the copied element from the website that I am attempting to change. Once again, when I inspect this element and then change the style directly in the inspect menu I can make the desired change.

```
<section class="page-section

  layout-engine-section

background-width--full-bleed

  section-height--medium


  content-width--wide

horizontal-alignment--center
vertical-alignment--middle

white" data-section-id="5db3673a86bd8571acb9b055" data-controller="SectionWrapperController, MagicPaddingController" data-current-styles="{
&quot;video&quot; : {
&quot;playbackSpeed&quot; : 0.5,
&quot;filter&quot; : 1,
&quot;filterStrength&quot; : 0,
&quot;zoom&quot; : 0
},
&quot;backgroundWidth&quot; : &quot;background-width--full-bleed&quot;,
&quot;sectionHeight&quot; : &quot;section-height--medium&quot;,
&quot;customSectionHeight&quot; : 10,
&quot;horizontalAlignment&quot; : &quot;horizontal-alignment--center&quot;,
&quot;verticalAlignment&quot; : &quot;vertical-alignment--middle&quot;,
&quot;contentWidth&quot; : &quot;content-width--wide&quot;,
&quot;customContentWidth&quot; : 50,
&quot;sectionTheme&quot; : &quot;white&quot;,
&quot;sectionAnimation&quot; : &quot;none&quot;,
&quot;backgroundMode&quot; : &quot;image&quot;
}" data-animation="none" style="padding-top: 98.8125px;" data-controllers- 
bound="SectionWrapperController, MagicPaddingController" data-active="true" 
id="yui_3_17_2_1_1572553417171_403">
```

Comment: You're able to do CSS changes, right? If so look for the exact class name and try to add a color gradient to that class name.

Comment: The CSS you are injecting is probably being overwritten after the fact. Either find where it is actually specified and change it there, add an !important tag, or apply the styles directly to the tag

Comment: Hey guys thanks for the input. I am really not fluent in CSS or HTML, I am assuming the class here is page-section and I am not quite sure how to add an !important tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track. There are just a few things you're missing. Here they are:

1. Any id attribute in Squarespace that starts with `yui` is a dynamically assigned ID, which means it will change with every refresh of the page. If you see an id attribute starting with `yui` do not use it in your CSS. Instead, find a different way to select/target the element.
2. In Squarespace 7, you could use section ids in your CSS (they weren't dynamically generated). However, based on the code you copy/pasted, you are using a Squarespace template of version 7.1, which means you'll need to use the `data-section-id` attribute instead to target a specific section. If you read something that told you to use the id of a section to target it, that information was likely referring to Squarespace 7, not the template version you're using, which is 7.1. Attribute selectors use a bracketed syntax, and are not as straightforward as ids and classes. But it's not too difficult. Read [more about attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) if you want to.
3. Even if you could use the id attribute, your code may not work as you intend it to. If that's true, it could be because you have a space between the id and the `.page-section` class. In CSS that means "target elements with 'page-section' class that are *descendants* of the element with the given id". What you may want is to target the section that has the given id itself. To do this, remove the space between the id and the class.

Bringing that all together, you end up with:

```
[data-section-id="5db3673a86bd8571acb9b055"].page-section {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, black, blue);
}
```

Note that in the above code, you could technically get rid of the `.page-section` part of the selector and it would still work fine (assuming you're trying target a section with that id). I included it purely for demonstration of point #3 above. Of course, if you are trying to target a descendant, leave the space and set the class accordingly.

Comment: wow this is a really awesome, helpful and informative answer. Sadly it still doesn't seem to be working...is there any other information I can provide you that may be helpful? Thank you so much again.

Comment: Wait just got it! Your tip on the spaces between the descendants and stuff was extremely helpful. I realized that I think I really was meaning to target `.section-background` which is a descendant of that specific id. Either way, `[data-section-id="5db3673a86bd8571acb9b055"] .section-background` worked!